# Can I post same message multiple times in twitter

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, sharekit

I am using shareKit for iPhone to support twitter, while posting same message second time on twitter  "duplicate status" alert is displayed.how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

No same message can't post multiple times because twitter every times check the body of the twits.

you need some after time to post on the twitter.